# Easy-admin array field overwrites values

Tags: symfony, easyadmin

I am using version 2.7.0 of Doctrine and 2.3.4 of **easycorp/easyadmin-bundle**. My class person has a pet arrangement

```php
/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * /
class person
{
    // ...


    / **
     * @ORM \ Column (type = "array")
     *
     * /
    private $ pets = [];
}
```

The form to create or edit the person object and their pets works well, but sometimes in the edit view some values ​​are overwritten.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution:**

To solve this, all you have to do is put the pet's annotations as **'simple_array'** instead of **'array'**. It would look like this:

```php
/**
 * @ORM \ Entity
 * /
class person
{
    // ...


    / **
     * @ORM \ Column (type = "simple_array")
     *
     * /
    private $ pets = [];
}
```

**Explanation:**

This happens because when you put a field like **array** then Doctrine in addition to saving the values ​​saves things like the index that had that value in the array, so if you have a person with the cat and dog values, it is stored as follows: **a: 2: {i: 0; s: 3: "cat"; i: 1; s: 3: "dog";}** which says that the arrangement has 2 elements, in the position 0 is cat and in position 1 is dog.

Then each time the view is generated for editing, two inputs will be created with the names:
**person[pets][0]** with the value **cat** and **person[pets][1]** with the value **dog**.

However, if you click on the **Add element** button, the amount of input that the form already has will be taken into account so that it creates a new one with the name **person[pets][2]**, if always you delete the last item in the list there will be no problems but if you remove for example the first input that has the name **person[pets][0]**, the amount of input will be of value 1, so the new input that is create will be with the name **person[pets][1]** so you will overwrite the value of **dog**.

However, when saving the field **pets** as **simple_array** in the database only the values ​​are saved: **cat, dog**, so every time the view is constructed to edit the indexes they will always start from scratch and will never be overwritten